# How to hide the sorting arrow in GXT3 grid?

Tags: search, grid, gxt

Use case: User initiate the search with the a search criteria and returned result displayed in GXT3 grid. Column sorting enabled in gxt3 grid so user could sort data by selecting column header and there is arrow to indicate the sort order in grid. if the user initiate search second time, I could be able to clear the user selected column and set default sorting but still sort arrow displayed in grid. How can I hide the sorting arrow in grid? Thanks for your time.

Clear sorting info:

```
PagingLoadConfig.getSortInfo().clear();
```

[Example basic grid](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:basicgrid)

**UPDATE:**

GXT Version : 3.0.6

```
    if (loadConfig.getSortInfo() != null && !loadConfig.getSortInfo().isEmpty()) {
            loadConfig.getSortInfo().clear();
            view.getDataGridWidget().getGrid().getView().refresh(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call refresh at grid view object after clearing the sort info of your list store. Here is the example code:

```
listStore.getSortInfo().clear();
grid.getView().refresh(true); // must be true, to include the grid header in refresh operation
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Could you please post more detail of your code? What version of gxt are you use? The code I post was using gxt 3.0.6.

Comment: getDataGridWidget.getGrid().getStore().getSortInfo() - list is always empty and sort info details exist only in PagingLoadConfig.getSortInfo()